# AngularJS syntax error / expected expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add a post method to my controller, but I keep getting a syntactical error that I can't trace. My goal is for a single controller to fetch() on init, and then have buttons within the controller that can call additem(itemid) on click.

Here's my app.js:

```
(function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.method = 'GET';
        $scope.url = '/path/to/api';
        $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;
      var response = $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
        then(function(response) {
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
          $scope.thedata = JSON.stringify(response.data);
          $scope.count = $scope.data.length
          console.log($scope.thedata);
          console.log($scope.data[0]);
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || "Request Failed";
          $scope.status = response.status;
        })
    };
    $scope.additem = function(itemid) {
      var itemdata = new Object();
      itemdata.itemid = itemid;
      $http.post($scope.url, itemdata).success(function(data){
          //Callback function here.
          //"data" is the response from the server.
          if (data.status === "success") {
            console.log("Added!")
          }
      });
    }
  }]),
]);   // SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'
})(window.angular);
```

On the line just before (window.angular); I get this error in the Firefox console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'
```

I'm pretty sure my indentation is a little messed up towards the end, so it's tough to discern what is causing it...

Comment: so just fix indentation, and you will see where is problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending the script like this corrected the syntax:

```
        };
      }
    ]);
});
(window.angular);
```